# how to compile project with uchar_t in ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation

I have a project source code

it contain uchar_t

I need to compile this project in Ubuntu 13.10
but when run compilation that it warn :

```
unknown type name ‘uchar_t’
```

anyone have idea to solve. replace uchar_t or other solution ...

Comment: And you're using g++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, `uchar_t` is meant to represent some character in which case you probably want to make it an `unsigned` character type, e.g.:

```
typedef unsigned char uchar_t;
```

Whether this works depends on what the code really intended to do. Without context it is impossible to tell what is intended. In either case, I would use a `typedef` in a strategic place rather than replacing the type. Likewise, `uint_t` is probably meant to be

```
typedef unsigned int uint_t;
```

Whether these `typedef`s do the right thing, needs to be verified, though.

Comment: can I use this solution for uint_t too?

Comment: `uchar_t` is common in many organizations and code bases to mean `unsigned char`--it has nothing to do with unicode.

Comment: @user1974446: You mean a `typedef`? Sure. Which type is intended, I don't know, however.

Comment: (Either way, it's an absolutely horrible typedef.)

Comment: @wallyk: adjusted the answer.

Comment: @H2CO3: agreed. However, if I had to patch up existing code using such a type all over the place, I'd rather use a `typedef` than replace the name: if the first attempt doesn't guess the correct type, it is one place which needs to be changed to try a different one.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yup, sounds reasonable. (it's not that it wouldn't work in this codebase -- I just wouldn't start using it in a new project.)

Comment: IM, unless you have a header that is included in all places that symbol is used, I'd add `-Duchar_t unsigned char` to your make file. That way you don't need to litter typedefs all over the place.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: that might work, but then again it might not because `unsigned char` is a different grammatical construction than `uchar_t`. Consider `uchar_t(0)`. So if it doesn't work you *have* to touch the source files, and the question is whether to do it by adding a header file and typedef to make `uchar_t` a simple type specifier as expected, or by touching the code. Also beware namespaces, `-D` is no use in the unpleasant event that `uchar_t` is shadowed somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

That is probably an alias for `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2):

The types `uchar_t`, `ushort_t`, `uint_t` and `ulong_t` are Solaris specific types defined in `sys/types.h` and commented as POSIX Extensions. That comment is ambiguous and probably means that they are (vendor specific) extensions to the POSIX standard, not that they're part of it. Some other systems define them, others not (cygwin, Linux). They are quite straight-forward and can be quickly replaced by adding

```
typedef unsigned char   uchar_t;
typedef unsigned short  ushort_t;
typedef unsigned int    uint_t;
typedef unsigned long   ulong_t;
```

somewhere in the project's headers. I like them a lot because they are shorter, 1 word, follow the POSIX and the `inttypes.h` naming style and are quite obvious.